# Error creating a PostgreSQL database with flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a table in a PostgreSQL database using a Flask.

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from send_mail import send_mail

app = Flask(__name__)

ENV = 'dev'

if ENV == 'dev':
    app.debug = True
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:0151@localhost:5432/reserva'
else:
    app.debug = False
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = ''

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Feedback(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'feedback'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)
    dealer = db.Column(db.String(200))
    rating = db.Column(db.Integer)
    comments = db.Column(db.Text())

    def __init__(self, customer, dealer, rating, comments):
        self.customer = customer
        self.dealer = dealer
        self.rating = rating
        self.comments = comments


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/submit', methods=['POST'])
def submit():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer = request.form['customer']
        dealer = request.form['dealer']
        rating = request.form['rating']
        comments = request.form['comments']
        # print(customer, dealer, rating, comments)
        if customer == '' or dealer == '':
            return render_template('index.html', message='Please enter required fields')
        if db.session.query(Feedback).filter(Feedback.customer == customer).count() == 0:
            data = Feedback(customer, dealer, rating, comments)
            db.session.add(data)
            db.session.commit()
            send_mail(customer, dealer, rating, comments)
            return render_template('success.html')
        return render_template('index.html', message='You have already submitted feedback')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

When I try to run `db.create_all()` this error is thrown:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3211, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 307, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 767, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 425, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 253, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 368, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 611, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 605, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 584, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1094, in create_all
    self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 1086, in _execute_for_all_tables
    op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\schema.py", line 4739, in create_all
    bind._run_ddl_visitor(
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3077, in _run_ddl_visitor
    with self.begin() as conn:
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2993, in begin
    conn = self.connect(close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3165, in connect
    return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 96, in __init__
    else engine.raw_connection()
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3244, in raw_connection
    return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3214, in _wrap_pool_connect
    Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 2068, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 3211, in _wrap_pool_connect
    return fn()
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 307, in connect
    return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 767, in _checkout
    fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 425, in checkout
    rec = pool._do_get()
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 146, in _do_get
    self._dec_overflow()
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 253, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 368, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 611, in __connect
    pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\pool\base.py", line 605, in __connect
    connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\create.py", line 578, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 584, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "C:\Users\janju\Documents\Apps\WEB\PRUEBAS\PYTHON\FLASK\app_flask\env\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError)
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Comment: The error message isn't very helpful, unfortunately; all it tells us is that something went wrong when trying to connect to the database server.  Is the database service running?  Are you able to connect successfully by any other method?  Are there any useful messages in the database server's logs?

Comment: thnks for ur answer, the service is runing, actually i'm using a node.js app to conect with PostgreSQL and... works...

all the error log is above, nothing else